# Most easily understandable way to turn a sequence of strings into an array of characters?

Tags: python, arrays, string, character

I have this:

```
sequence = 'Hello', 'Hi'
```

I want this:

```
array = 'H','e','l','l','o','H','i'
```

I can't get the formatting right. I keep getting a sequence of strings instead of one big array of characters.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> sequence = 'Hello', 'Hi'
>>> sequence
('Hello', 'Hi')
```

This expression is called `Tuple assignment`:

The left side is a tuple of variables; the right side is a tuple of expressions.

So you need to iterate over the tuple(`sequence`) to get each character from elements(`word`).

```
>>> string_array = [char for i in sequence for char in i]
>>> string_array
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'H', 'i']
```

Efficiency of `itertools` are less in comparison.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> import timeit
>>> using_chain = lambda: tuple(chain.from_iterable(sequence))
>>> timeit.timeit(using_chain)
1.7286441326141357
>>> using_for = lambda: [ char for i in sequence for char in i]
>>> timeit.timeit(using_for)
1.345189094543457
```

Or you can use generator expression here.

```
>>> string_array = (char for i in sequence for char in i)
>>> string_array
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0231BD78>
>>> tuple(string_array)
('H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'H', 'i')
```

More on `Tuple assignment`:

The left side is a tuple of variables; the right side is a tuple of expressions`(the right side can be any kind of sequence (string, list or tuple))`. Each value is assigned to its respective variable. All the expressions on the right side are evaluated before any of the assignments.

```
>>> a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> c
3
```

The number of variables on the left and the number of values on the right have to be the same:

```
>>> a,b = 1, 2, 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Note :- Unpacking only occurs when there are more than one variable on the left side else the whole sequence is assigned to that single variable.(`this is what happened in your case`)

```
>>> a = 'I', 'love', 'Python'
>>> a
('I', 'love', 'Python')
```

Comment: Or, if he really wants a tuple as in his desired output, `tuple(char for i in sequence for char in i)`.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks, exactly the output has to be tuple as it was a tuple expression.

Comment: use `itertools.chain` will be better.

Comment: @VishnuUpadhyay itertools.chain are great but has less efficiency as compared to normal iteration. See i have updated my answer. But thanks for the advice.

Comment: what do you mean efficiant here for iterators, check my answer i update it.

Comment: @VishnuUpadhyay I have added the time required to execute it with itertools and without it.

Comment: @Chris Flammang If you feel that the above answer is correct as per your question, it would be great if you accept it so that it would be helpful for me as well as others who face this same problem in future.

Answer (score 1):

by    `sequence = 'Hello' , 'Hi'`
you are creating a tuple

so just iterate through each element as:

```
arr = []
for string in sequence:
     for char in string:
        arr.append(char)
```

Answer (score 1):

simply use `itertools.chain.from_iterable()`

```
In [152]: a
Out[152]: ('Hello', 'Hi')

In [136]: from itertools import chain       
In [146]: list(chain.from_iterable(a))
Out[146]: ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'H', 'i']
```

as compared to naormal iteration for large values

```
In [154]: %timeit list(chain.from_iterable(a*10**5))
10 loops, best of 3: 49.8 ms per loop

In [155]: %timeit [char for i in a*10**5 for char in i]
10 loops, best of 3: 68 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
arr = []
for i in sequence:
    for j in i:
       arr.append(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest form would be:

```
array = sequence[0] + sequence[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple solution:

```
result_array = []

for word in sequence:
  result_array += list(word)
```